# mat-form-field not visible

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material. When creating a form, I need to add several inputs. However, if you add more than three, the rest will not appear until they have focus.

```
<div class="form">
  <h2 class="form__title">Регистрация</h2>
  <form [formGroup]="registerForm">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Введите телефон</mat-label>
      <input formControlName="userPhone" required matInput>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Введите email</mat-label>
      <input formControlName="userEmail" type="email" required matInput>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Введите пароль</mat-label>
      <input type="password" formControlName="userPassword" required matInput>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Test</mat-label>
      <input required matInput>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button (click)="onSubmit()" mat-raised-button class="form__button" color="primary">Зарегистрироваться</button>
    <div class="form__bottom">
      Уже есть аккаунт? <a routerLink="/auth/login">Войти</a>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you add a `formControlName` to it?

Comment: More than 3 mat-form-fields are not displayed on one page.

Comment: `<input required matInput>` needs a type and binding to a form control

Comment: Can you share the ts file as well?